# How to store math equation/symbol and display them on the web?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, math, web

I want to build a website where people can create tests with questions and answers . I want people can type in math equation/symbol and equations in a textbox or something like that, and they will be store in database, it'also displayed on the web like image.

My idea is i will store the text user input in latex syntax and store it, then display it using MathJax, i don't know it's possible or will have better way to do this.

And a problem is in user input will have normal text with "math text" (latex), so how can i separate them and only save the latex text?  Please give me some idea or suggest the way to solve it, thanks.

p/s: i'm building this site in ruby on rails, i found the gem mathjax-rails but it seem not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider building off [Gollum](https://github.com/github/gollum).  It is the backend for the wiki system Github uses and works fairly well with LaTex equations (currently their is a very irritating bug with less/greater than symbols, but is documented and likely will be fixed in the next release).  I start using it this summer to take notes in a math classes, an example of a full page of rendered LaTex equations notes is here [here](https://github.com/KurtRudolph/math461/wiki/lecture_03).

**Note:** You must be logged into Github in order for the equation to render.

Comment: It's very nice! can it used in views of rails ?

Comment: In short yes, [here](https://github.com/assimovt/gollum-rails/blob/master/app/views/pages/show.haml) is a decent demo application... In long, I wouldn't phrase it "use in views of rails" but you are able to combine the two in manor which allows you to display gollum rendered wiki's within the views of your rails application.  You will also want to check out the [gollum api documentation](http://rubydoc.info/gems/gollum/2.1.4/frames).

Comment: Thanks so much, it's is what i looking for, it's pity i can't vote up for your answer :D